# MS, at management science

Tags: word-usage

Is "at" used as an indicator to point to the true meaning of "MS"?

> MS, at management science
> MS, at Master of Science
> ms, at millisecond
> MS, at MSc
> MS, at multiple sclerosis
> M.S., at Master of Science

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ms?q=ms.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not "true meaning" as such, but rather "an additional meaning" or "you may find what you are looking for at this location".

If you look at the heading of the quoted section (in yellow) it reads "More meanings of *ms*." It then lists a number of pages where "ms" can be found in specified sections of the definition (probably title and abbreviations; it is found by computerized query, I am sure).

Thus, it lists two selections that contain "ms" (MS-DOS, MSc) and the remainder of the selections all have "ms" as an abbreviation (e.g. "milliseconds").